# JSON API variable attach to multiple elements

Tags: c#, json, api, xaml, uwp

I have a `UWP` project that I'm currently working on where I use a `SQL` database to store values and a `Json API` to get the values from the database into `Visual studio`.

Right now I have no problems with reaching the values, and no problems with get the values into `c#` variables. The values that comes from the database is different rooms and with them is all the attributes to them and all the bookings.

When I dezerialise the values of the rooms I do like this:

```
string url = "https://api.booking.com/api/company/a8fdbd0c-c0e4-470d-82b7-2b06a1a58dd8/rooms";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
List<Class2> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class2>>(response);

foreach (Class2 room in data)
{

}
```

And that gets all the values of the rooms without problem. And then inside the `foreach` loop I get all the booking values like this:

```
string booking = $"https://api.booking.com/api/company/a8fdbd0c-c0e4-470d-82b7-2b06a1a58dd8/rooms/{room.id}/bookings";
HttpClient BookingClient = new HttpClient();
string BookingResponse = await BookingClient.GetStringAsync(booking);
List<Bookings> bookings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Bookings>>(BookingResponse);
room.Bookings = bookings;

foreach (var books in bookings)
{

}
```

Under that part I make a new `foreach` like above and make this happen inside that `foreach`:

```
if (books.timeFrom == Now)
{
    ToRed();
}
```

What I try to achieve here is that when the variable `timeFrom` is the same as `DateTime.Now` there is a color that I want to be changed. And that is working perfectly.

So to my problem....

Let's say that I have a room that is booked 09:00 AM. Then I want the color to change only on that specific room that is booked, but right now the color changes on every room there is...

The `Json` of a booking looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "a8fdbd0c-c0e4-470d-82b7-2b06a1a58dd8",
    "code": 4221,
    "timeFrom": "2018-06-14T09:00:00",
    "timeTo": "2018-06-14T10:00:00",
    "note": null,
    "createdDate": "2018-02-12T15:46:25.483",
    "room": {
      "name": "Rum 2",
      "id": "a8fdbd0c-c0e4-470d-82b7-2b06a1a58dd8",
      "seats": 5,
      "availableFrom": null,
      "availableTo": null,
      "roomAttributes": [

      ]
    }
  }
```

As you can se the booking have a variable that is called `room` so that must be a good way of telling which room to target by using that variable, but I have tried around so much now with no progress...

EDIT 1:

I have my room template in a `UserControl` like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock x:Name="CompanyName" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding RoomName}" FontSize="30" Margin="10,0,116,0" Width="257"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="StatusColor" x:FieldModifier="public" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="218" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And I call thet template from the `MainPage.xaml` like this:

```
<GridView x:Name="GridView1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource testgrid}" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Rooms}" Width="1740" Height="835" IsHitTestVisible="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="75,190,75,100" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False">
   <GridView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Room">
           <local:TemplateGrid x:Name="TemplateGrid"/>
       </DataTemplate>
   </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

EDIT 2:

This is the content inside the bookings `Foreach` :

```
var BeforeEnd = books.timeTo.Subtract(Now).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
var BeforeBegin = books.timeFrom.Subtract(Now).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));

if (books.timeFrom <= Now && books.timeTo > Now)
{
     ToRed();
     DispatcherTimer ColorTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
     ColorTimer.Interval = BeforeEnd;
     ColorTimer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
     {
         ToYellow();
         ColorTimer.Stop();
     };
     ColorTimer.Start();
 }
 else if (books.timeFrom > Now)
 {
     DispatcherTimer ColorTimer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
     ColorTimer2.Interval = BeforeBegin;
     ColorTimer2.Tick += (sender, args) =>
     {
          ToYellow();
          ColorTimer2.Stop();
     };
     ColorTimer2.Start();
 }
 else if (books.timeTo == Now)
 {
     ToGreen();
 }
```

Comment: You can Bind the XAML element Background to the Booking variable, and create a Converter to ser the Color Brush that you want.

Comment: I have a Template of a room that I bind everything on @Tony

Comment: No, cant really get it to work :( @NicoZhu-MSFT

Comment: please show more.

Comment: The part where you get the `JSON` you get it from a Text file. But I have my `JSON` inside a API. How do I solve that? :) @NicoZhu-MSFT

Comment: I get the json from a text file is just for testing easily. And it is same as Json that come from API. You just deserialize it to match object then create mirror ViewModel to bind.

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, you could make `IsAvailable` bool property  in the `RoomObject` class. And use a timer to handle `IsAvailable` value for each item just like the following.

```
public class RoomObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }

    }

    public RoomObject(Item dataSourece)
    {
        this.dataSourece = dataSourece;
        ModifyAvilable();
    }

    private void ModifyAvilable()
    {
        this.Name = dataSourece.room.name;
        DispatcherTimer startTimer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) };
        startTimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.IsAvailable = true;
            DispatcherTimer endTimer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) };
            endTimer.Tick += (o, p) =>
            {
                this.IsAvailable = false;
                endTimer.Stop();
            };
            endTimer.Start();
            startTimer.Stop();
        };
        startTimer.Start();
    }

    public Item dataSourece;

    private bool _isAvailable;
    public bool IsAvailable
    {
        get
        {
            return _isAvailable;
        }
        set
        {
            _isAvailable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

**MainPageViewModel**

```
 public class MainPageViewModel
 {
     public MainPageViewModel()
     {
         GetJson();
     }
     public ObservableCollection<RoomObject> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<RoomObject>();
     private async void GetJson()
     {
         var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("json.txt");
         string json = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
         var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(json);
         var roomitem = new RoomObject(item);
         Items.Add(roomitem);
     }  

 }
```

**Xaml Usage**

```
<Grid>
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Height="100" Width="100" Background="Red">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Rectangle Height="20" Width="20" Fill="{Binding IsAvailable,Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>

    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

And I have uploaded the full code sample, please refer [this](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/RoomBookTest.git).

Comment: Thanks for the good answer! When you say Model class, is it the code behind of the template you mean? Or is it the bookings class?

Comment: Yes, any question?

Comment: I found your have passed nothing to your user control

Comment: Yeah,  about the xaml usage. Don't really understand why I need to do a new `DataTemplate`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173540/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-luddep).

Comment: if you use `UserControl` as the content of `DataTemplate` you could use t
`<local:MyUserControl1 DataContext="{Binding}"/>`.